# How to get column name according to value? impossible?

Tags: php, mysql

Recently im stuck with this code...

I would like to know the column_name that matches the value...

For Example:

I have a table called favorite with userID and 5 favorite columns which stores restaurant's ID as follows:

[image: mySQL table]

I printed them into a listview and when i delete them, i get the restaurantID and then search for the columns that equals to the value, then update the column into NULL.

Sorry if my question confused you... I myself is confusing.

so how should i do the SELECT statement? or i shall straight away UPDATE?
like

```
SELECT $column from favorite WHERE loginID= 'admin' AND $column = '99'?
```

or

```
UPDATE favorite SET $column = 'NULL' WHERE loginID = 'admin'?
```

what should the $column be? >.<

Comment: You really should think about normalizing your database. Instead of having x different columns, build a table with fields loginID and favoriteID...then every user can have an arbitrary amount of favorites and you can easily delete entries with `WHERE loginID = ? AND favoriteID = ?`.

Comment: Thanks! its the same suggestion from @ZombieHunter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and create a proper database schema like:

Table login:

```
loginID | name
      1 |  foo
      2 |  bar
```

Table login_favorite:

```
loginID | favoriteID
      1 |          1
      1 |          2
      2 |          2
```

Table favorite

```
favoriteID | name | ...
         1 |  foo | ...
         2 |  bar | ...
```

Now JOIN these tables and enjoy the feeling of having a clean database...

Comment: is it possible to squeeze in 1 table? if it is impossible or very complicated, probably i'll use your way =D

Comment: Everything is possible, but it's not clean and every developer working with your schema might eventually think about lynching you :-)

Comment: isn't the (login_favorite) table as mention by you become useless , if i added a column of loginID into favorite table.

Comment: @PolarBear: No. This way you could assign a favorite to only one login. Thats not what you want...